# Use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` with `MPRemoteCommandCenter`

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, avspeechsynthesizer, mpremotecommandcenter

I need to use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to read a text to my user.

User will control reading with AirPods, so I need to use `MPRemoteCommandCenter`.

For now, I need to prepare my audio files using `AVSpeechSynthesizer.write(_:toBufferCallback:)` the create a playlist and read it using `AVQueuePlayer`.

It works. But preparing audio files take time. I prefer to use `AVSpeechSynthesizer.speak(_:)` directly in background mode, and activate it via `MPRemoteCommandCenter` commands.

Is this possible? Or perhaps any workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same issue, and now figure out
the only thing you need to do

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
```

at the begining. don't use `.duckOthers`, `.mixWithOthers`

addTarget to RemoteCommand

```
func addRemoteCommandCenter() {
    let rcc = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    //添加暂停监听
    rcc.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playOrPauseEvent(_:)))
    //添加播放监听
    rcc.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playOrPauseEvent(_:)))
    //下一首
    rcc.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextCommandEvent(_:)))
    //上一首
    rcc.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previousCammndEvent(_:)))
    //耳机暂停和播放的监听
    rcc.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(togglePlayPauseCommand(_:)))
}
```

at the `speechSynthesizer(_:didStart:)` and `speechSynthesizer(_:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:)` update the UI

```
        let infoCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()        
    infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:"Title", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Artist", MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: "", MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120), requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
           UIImage()
    })]
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thank you! In fact, remote is enabled once `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` is updated and once I play first item.